# two hot dogs per day, one turkey sandwich day and two mini pizzas per day

Tags: sentence-construction

My scenario is given below.

Every weekend, you buy enough food for the following week's lunch. You want two hot dogs for lunch ANY two days (That's four hot dogs in total). You need one turkey for lunch ANY three days (That's three sandwiches in total). I also have two mini pizzas for lunch for EACH of the remaining days of the week (That's four mini pizzas in total).

One example is: I may have two hot dogs each day (Mon and Thu), one sandwich each day (Tue, Wed, and Sun), and two pizzas each day (Fri and Sat).

Another example is: I may have two hot dogs each day (Wed and Sun), one sandwich each day (Mon, Tue, and Fri), and two pizzas each day (Thu and Sat).

This is totally random.

I know I'm being wordy here because I want to make things very clear for my question.

Suppose that you are telling your friend about what food you need to buy for next week's lunch.

**(1) For next week's lunch, I want to buy four hot dogs, two per day; three turkey sandwiches, one  per day; and four mini pizzas, two per day.**

Is my sentence understandable?

Comment: What is your actual problem in English.  I don't think you really have a friend who wants to know about your lunch. Do you have a real problem?  What do you actually want to do?  Do you want to tell your friend "about what food you need to buy"  or do you also need to tell them how many hot dogs you eat in one serving.  One rule for clear English is that each sentence should do one thing  well.  So there should be two or three sentences here, if you need to tell your friend two or three things

Comment: That is a really poor, unhealthy diet, also.

Comment: Question was never clarified.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to buy 4 hot dogs, 3 turkey sandwiches and 4 mini pizza's

---

your friend is not interested when you want to eat them, you do not need to tell him and it's just confusing anyway.

---

And No! your statement was not easily understandable! It is confusing. Understanding is the Art of good communication.

Comment: This does fulfil the task of "telling your friend about what food you need to buy for next week's lunch."

Comment: However your edit is a bit silly and point-making. Hopefully the OP will clarify what their actual problem is, and so we won't have to guess.

Comment: Agreed, it is stupid, that is why I did not originally post anything like that, And why now that my point has at last been grasped I will remove it.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically correct, but that does not mean that everyone will grasp it. Here is how I would convey it to make sure anyone will understand it.

> For lunch, I eat hot dogs twice per week, a turkey sandwich thrice per week, and mini-pizzas twice per week. When I have hot dogs, I eat two. When I have turkey, I eat one sandwich. When I have mini-pizzas, I eat two. Thus, my weekly shopping list includes four hot dogs, three turkey sandwiches, and four mini-pizzas.

Conciseness may be a stylistic virtue, but comprehensibility is the ultimate virtue. Asking people to do mental arithmetic, even very simple mental arithmetic, leads to comprehensibility only with very restricted audiences. I speak from experience: if you want people to understand you, do not give them ratios to manipulate in their heads.

Comment: sorry Jeff the English is great but I could not remember it all if I went to Tesco. Just my "My weekly shopping list includes four hot dogs, three turkey sandwiches, and four mini-pizzas", would have been great.

Comment: @Brad Yes, well the question was how to convey the entirety of that information in a way comprehensible to normal English speakers. The question was not whether it makes any sense to convey that particular information. I presume that the questioner is not really interested in explaining why he eats turkey sandwiches that are a week old, but instead is interested in how to convey information about pairs of ratios. I try to answer what I think the question is actually about rather than how to deal with a ridiculous example about soggy sandwiches.

Comment: Yet again saddled with an impossible task, but not every pony trots around the track?

Comment: This is a good way to communicate all the information to the friend.  You should use multiple sentences as Jeff has done.

Comment: Gentlemen, you seem to have missed the point, The only comprehensible things in the statement.  **For next week's lunch, I want to buy four hot dogs, two per day; three turkey sandwiches, one per day; and four mini pizzas, two per day**. is** 4 hot dogs, 3 turkey sandwiches and 4 mini pizza's** Jeff has assumed he eats *2 hot dogs twice per week* But that's not what it says It actually says he wants to buy 4 hotdogs but you can only buy 2 hot dogs each day. And this goes on per rata for the other food. It also does not tell you what or when he will consume each item.

Comment: If we use Jeff's assumed  buying in bulk **For lunch, I eat hot dogs twice per week, a turkey sandwich thrice per week, and mini-pizzas twice per week. When I have hot dogs, I eat two. When I have turkey, I eat one sandwich. When I have mini-pizzas, I eat two.** Is all **irrelevant** because  his friend does not want to know; he has no use for this information because when the food is eaten is random. "I" already knows this, he is the source of the info.  Therefore the only statement required is **my weekly shopping list includes four hot dogs, three turkey sandwiches, and four mini-pizzas**.

Comment: @Brad You think the additional information is irrelevant. The OP, however, asked how to convey that information. Our job is to explain how to use English to convey the meaning that the OP spent several paragraphs specifying rather than to express an **opinion** on its relevance with obscure metaphors about saddled ponies on a track.

Comment: Two times per week, three times per week, and two times per week are not random, but perfectly well defined and are ratios. With each passing day, the degrees of freedom reduce until, on the final day of the week, there is no uncertainty at all. Random does not mean irrelevant.

Comment: **Quote** Suppose that you are **telling your friend about what food you need to buy for next week's lunch**.  please note that there is not reference to the fact he wishes to explain to his friend why he wants to buy the food. **The OP has not asked us to explain why**.  The  resulting list of what he needs to buy is **four hot dogs, three turkey sandwiches, and four mini-pizzas**. The OP's question was **Is my sentence understandable?** and the answer must be **No** Most of the OP's post (Above random) is irrelevant and could be edited out.

Comment: I will post no further comments on this question. I can see that your English is very good and I respect you in this regard and your presence on this site. It is the Post that is the problem. I have answered what I conclude from the post. You have answered what you think is required and I think I should respect that we have the right of our own opinions.

Comment: @Brad Indeed. Reasoned differences of opinion should be respected. And I agree that the post is the problem. If it is truly what he wants to express, it is a bunch of stuff that anyone will find irrelevant.

Answer (score -1):

No, your sentence is not understandable.

If you say, *I want to buy four hot dogs, two per day,* I understand that to mean you will be going to the store on two separate days and buying two hotdogs each time.  You will ultimately have purchased four hotdogs, two per day.  Based on what you are telling me, all I know about your hotdogs is that you plan to buy them.
You haven't informed me how you plan to use them before you tell me *two per day*.  I must assume *two per day* refers to your buying the hotdogs.  The same understanding would apply to your turkey sandwiches and mini pizzas.

If you would like to share the rate at which you will be using the hotdogs and the days that you will be using them, you must clearly differentiate that from the activity of buying the hotdogs.  I would suggest two sentences for clarity.  One sentence detailing the rate at which you plan to use them
and possibly another sentence summarizing the totals.

> Over the course of the next week I need to serve two hotdogs each day on two separate days, a turkey sandwich on three separate days, and two mini pizzas each day on two separate days.

or

> Over the course of the next week I need to serve hotdogs twice, two dogs per serving, mini pizzas twice, which are also two per serving, and a turkey sandwich three times.

The above statements say all you need to say but if you want to provide a tally of the totals, you could add a summarizing sentence -

> So I will want to buy 4 hot dogs, 3 turkey sandwiches and 4 mini pizza's.